# $a_n\leq b_n <a_n+c_n$ -- convergence for strictly smaller

Tags: analysis

I have a very stupid question!

Suppose $a_n\leq b_n <a_n+\frac{1}{n}$ and $a_n\to a$ as $n\to\infty$.

Does this imply $b_n\to a$ as $n\to\infty$, although we have that $b_n$ is **strictly smaller** instead of $b_n\leq a_n$?

Comment: So you have $a_n<a_n$?

Comment: How can $a\le b < a$ ?

Comment: Perhaps you meant $a_n \le b_n < a_{n+1}$?

Comment: Sorry, I mean something like $a_n\leq b_n< a_n+c_n$ where $a_n\to a$ and $c_n\to 0$. Does this imply $b_n\to a$?

Comment: I mean a general setting where $a_n\leq b_n < c_n$ and both $a_n$ and $c_n$ have the same limit. Does this imply that $b_n$ also tends to this limit, although there is a "strictly less" an the right-hand side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed.

Let $a_{n}$, $b_{n}$ and $c_{n}$ be real-valued sequences s.t. $a_{n} < b_{n} < c_{n}$ where $a_{n}\to L$ and $c_{n}\to L$.

Then we can conclude that $b_{n}\to L$.

In order to prove so, consider a $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there corresponds $n^{1}_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n^{2}_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t.
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
n\geq n^{1}_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow L - \varepsilon < a_{n} < L + \varepsilon\\\\
n\geq n^{2}_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow L - \varepsilon < c_{n} < L + \varepsilon
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Consequently, if we choose $n_{\varepsilon} = \max\{n^{1}_{\varepsilon},n^{2}_{\varepsilon}\}$, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
n\geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow L - \varepsilon < a_{n} < b_{n} < c_{n} < L + \varepsilon \Rightarrow |b_{n} - L| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}
whence we deduce that $b_{n}\to L$, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If $a_{n}\le b_{n} \le c_{n}$ and $a_{n}$ and $c_{n}$ go to $a$ as $n\to \infty$ then $b_{n}\to a$ as well . This is known as the squeeze theorem .